# Cryptic message by HP support assistant

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, hp-pavilion

I've recently reinstalled Win7 on my HP Pavillion dv6 laptop and I keep getting this cryptic message from HP support assistant shortly after startup. The computer seems to be working fine otherwise (if a bit slow).

[image: error window]

Detailed message with Event Viewer:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. mscorlib 

at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner) 

at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner) 

at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) 

at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args) at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter) 

at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler) Root element is missing.
```

Comment: Look if you can find a better message in the Event Viewer.

Comment: @harrymc I've edited the post to include what Event Viewer has

Comment: Could you better format the text?

Comment: Why?  It’s a .NET unhandled exception.  The details are not helpful.  What is clear is that the exception is due to an XML file.  The HP assistant should be uninstalled and the current version installed.

Comment: More than likely you have an outdated version of HPSA, download and install the latest version....https://www8.hp.com/us/en/campaigns/hpsupportassistant/hpsupport.html

Answer (score 1):

The "cryptic" message is due to a problem with an XML file. Reinstall the HP software. If the error persists, contact HP support.